# the name '' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, public, netmq

Hi I can't fix the issue in OnLoginSuccess() `pubSocket.SendMoreFrame("TopicA").SendFrame("Hello");` variable due to error
the name '' does not exist in the current context.

I know that I need to change variable to public but when I add 
`static public PublisherSocket pubSocket = new PublisherSocket();`
at the beggining of the class the code doues not work properly.
Also, the problem is that I need to set some options (.Options, .Bind) in Main().

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using NetMQ;
using NetMQ.Sockets;

namespace Publisher
{
class Program
{

    static public void OnLoginSuccess()
    {
        pubSocket.SendMoreFrame("TopicA").SendFrame("Hello");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        using (var pubSocket = new PublisherSocket())
        {
            pubSocket.Options.SendHighWatermark = 1000;
            pubSocket.Bind("tcp://localhost:12345");             
        }

        OnLoginSuccess();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your pubSocket is only declared in your Main(), not in OnLoginSuccess

Comment: It sounds like you need to *declare* the variable as a static field, but you can still *initialize* it in `Main`. (Or potentially change your design so that you pass it to `OnLoginSuccess()` instead.)

Comment: The other issue would be that `pubSocket` would also be disposed by the time `onLoginSuccess` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed, either create a private static variable in the class

```
private static PublisherSocket  pubSocket;
```

or pass the socket reference into your OnLoginSuccess method.

```
 static public void OnLoginSuccess(PublisherSocket socket)
 {
       socket.SendMoreFrame("TopicA").SendFrame("Hello");
 }
```

As Evan pointed out, your ref would have been disposed of due to the using notation. Remove this and dispose once you've finished with it.

```
 var pubSocket = new PublisherSocket()
 {
       pubSocket.Options.SendHighWatermark = 1000;
       pubSocket.Bind("tcp://localhost:12345");
 };

 OnLoginSuccess(pubSocket);
 pubSocket.Dispose();
```

You might want to put your call in a try catch finally and put the dispose in the finally to ensure it is cleaned up correctly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! I added 'private static PublisherSocket  pubSocket;' and code start works!

Comment: @sortedMAn - That's great. Please feel free to upvote and select as your answer :)